# ggplotting of kmeans Clustering and map coordinances

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, k-means

Is there a way how to combine `ggplot` map and `ggplot` of Kmeans Clustering

I have a dataset of regins - I am able to create a ggplot of each regions, then I am clustering coordiances using kmeans algorhitm and also can plot results in ggplot

however combining both plots is an issue for me:

```
rm(list = ls())

library(leaflet)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(spdep)
library(leaflet.minicharts)
library(leafletCN)

# Regions of each country selected

URL <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_DEU_1_sp.rds"
data <- readRDS(url(URL))

URL2 <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_CZE_1_sp.rds"
data2 <- readRDS(url(URL2))

URL3 <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_POL_1_sp.rds"
data3 <- readRDS(url(URL3))

URL4 <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_SVK_1_sp.rds"
data4 <- readRDS(url(URL4))

URL5 <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_AUT_1_sp.rds"
data5 <- readRDS(url(URL5))

# Country borders of all countries

B_URL <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_DEU_0_sp.rds"
Bdata <- readRDS(url(B_URL))

B_URL2 <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_CZE_0_sp.rds"
Bdata2 <- readRDS(url(B_URL2))

B_URL3 <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_POL_0_sp.rds"
Bdata3 <- readRDS(url(B_URL3))

B_URL4 <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_SVK_0_sp.rds"
Bdata4 <- readRDS(url(B_URL4))

B_URL5 <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_AUT_0_sp.rds"
Bdata5 <- readRDS(url(B_URL5))

A <- rbind(data, data2, data3, data4, data5)
data_df <- data.frame(coordinates(A))

mapgg <- 
  ggplot(A, aes(x = long, y =lat))+
  geom_polygon(aes(group = group), color = "black", fill = FALSE)+
  geom_point(data = data_df, aes(x = X1, y = X2), size = 2.5, color = "red")

mapgg

# Kmeans Clusterring of Coordinances =========

Kmean_cord <- coordinates(A) %>% kmeans(centers = 4)
Kmean_cord

ggkmeans <- broom::augment(Kmean_cord, coordinates(A)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(X1, X2)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = .cluster, fill = .cluster)) + 
  stat_ellipse(aes(x=X1,y=X2,fill=factor(.cluster)),
               geom="polygon", level=0.95, alpha=0.2)


ggkmeans

# Combining 2 ggplots not working:
mapgg +
  ggkmeans
```

Comment: it's not ideal to start your reproducible example with `rm(list = ls())`. Also, do you really need all those packages for your code?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the error message. You are combining two ggproto objects with `+` - that's generally not possible without packages such as `patchwork` - and the latter will also just put them next to one another. Maybe just try to add the second plot without the ggplot main call to the first one - the data needs then to be added to both `geom_point` and `stat_ellipse` call